How to solve the problem of garbled code in ENVI?
The version of ENVI is 5.0,I just installed it, how to solve it?
I want to turn it into a normal Chinese display, so I change the Windows system language display, but it didn't work. The version of ENVI is 5.0,I just installed it, how to solve it?
